# Viewing underlying XML response when using xml-rpc.net

Tags: vb.net, xml-rpc

Is there a way to view the actual underlying xml data that the cookcomputing.xmlrpc.net library returns?  From what I can tell, it is only exposed via the xmlrpcstruct that the object creates based on the xml.

However, I am getting XmlRpcInvalidXmlRpcException exceptions, and am trying to understand the problem.

I am using an https connection.

Thanks!

-R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with this library but I suppose that it will finally boil down to a [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) for which you could [activate the trace in app.config](http://blogs.msdn.com/dgorti/archive/2005/09/18/471003.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't initially realize this was so old, but it turned up as a 'related' question to things I was looking for. I figured I'd throw in the way I do logging with xml-rpc.net. It will spit out the request XML and response XML to specified directory. Default directory is C:\ I believe.

Create an instance of RequestResponseLogger and attach it to your proxy.

> RequestResponseLogger logger= new RequestResponseLogger();
>                   logger.Directory = "C:\xmlrpclogs";
>                   proxy.AttachLogger(logger);

Comment: Thanks! I think the last line is logger.Attach(proxy).